# Spring Discord4J server Stopped

Tags: java, spring-boot, discord4j

I tried to create a discord bot with Discord4J. When i start the application it connect to the discord but then it stopped. I follow some recent tuto which used the same things and it works... I don't know why it doesn't work here...

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class GodCreatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GodCreatorApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

BotConfiguration :

```
import discord4j.core.DiscordClientBuilder;
import discord4j.core.GatewayDiscordClient;
import discord4j.core.event.domain.Event;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class BotConfiguration {
    @Value("${discord.token}")
    private String token;

    @Bean
    public <T extends Event> GatewayDiscordClient gatewayDiscordClient(List<EventListener<T>> eventListeners) {
        GatewayDiscordClient client = DiscordClientBuilder.create(token)
                .build()
                .login()
                .block();

        for(EventListener<T> listener : eventListeners) {
            assert client != null;
            client.on(listener.getEventType())
                    .flatMap(listener::execute)
                    .onErrorResume(listener::handleError)
                    .subscribe();
        }

        return client;
    }
}
```

MessageListener :

```
import discord4j.core.object.entity.Message;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public abstract class MessageListener {

    public Mono<Void> processCommand(Message eventMessage) {
        return Mono.just(eventMessage)
                .filter(message -> message.getAuthor().map(user -> !user.isBot()).orElse(false))
                .filter(message -> message.getContent().equalsIgnoreCase("!todo"))
                .flatMap(Message::getChannel)
                .flatMap(channel -> channel.createMessage("Things to do today:\n - write a bot\n - eat lunch\n - play a game"))
                .then();
    }
}
```

MassageCreateListener :

```
import discord4j.core.event.domain.message.MessageCreateEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Service
public class MessageCreateListener extends MessageListener implements EventListener<MessageCreateEvent> {

    @Override
    public Class<MessageCreateEvent> getEventType() {
        return MessageCreateEvent.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> execute(MessageCreateEvent event) {
        return processCommand(event.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And I have this result :

[image: There is the result]

Comment: There is not enough information here to assist. None of the relevant code is included. Please edit your question to include more information.

Comment: I add more information sorry

Answer (score 0):

Without the code in your `GodCreatorApplication` class it will be harder to help you. Nevertheless, it is most likely that you're not blocking the main thread and thus the JVS exits. I never used Spring so I cannot help you on how to implement this, but the D4J method to block until the bot is disconnected is `client.onDisconnect().block();`.